# Fibonacci in +!()[]script

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source, javascript, fibonacci

Write a piece of JavaScript code that calls `alert` with an array containing the first 50 Fibonacci numbers in order. You may only use the following characters: `+!()[]`.

As a reference, your code must be functionally equal to the following:

```
var fib = [], a = 1, b = 1;
for (var _ = 0; _ < 50; _++) {
    fib.push(a);
    var t = a; a = b; b = t + a;
}
alert(fib);
```

You may not assume any content on the webpage - your program will be run in the console on `about:blank`. Similarly, you may not 'cheat' and store any settings in cookies, settings or other data. Your solution must work on any fresh install of the latest Google Chrome **or** Firefox on any OS. When in doubt, try to remain as portable as possible.

---

Smallest source code in bytes wins.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what's wrong with the challenge?

Comment: By *functionally equal* do you mean that the solution must simulate `for` loops and appending variables, or do you just mean that the end result must be the same?

Comment: Downvotes may be due to the fact that this challenge, being single-language and fixed output, must have a single best solution. That's a bit frowned upon as it takes away some of the fun.

Comment: @BrainSteel Only the end result has to be the same.

Comment: @JohnE There is no way this question could even exist without being restricted to a single language, so that's not a valid concern. It is only a concern if the question would be __more fun__ if the restriction was lifted, which in this case is impossible. As for a single best solution, I don't think anyone will even get close - it's very complicated.

Comment: @trichoplax Hardcoding is a valid strategy.

Comment: @orlp Do we have to use `,` as a separator?

Comment: Voting to close. "Too broad" but really it's too narrow IMHO.

Comment: +1 Upvoting just because some of the criticism is absolutely ludicrious. A single best solution is always the case (and that's a good thing as well as it's still a Q&A site) and a challenge like this only makes sense when limited to a specific language (I mean, the skill is in finding a way to make the code shorter *not* in cheating by using a language that is inherently shorter).

Comment: @DavidMulder I wouldn't upvote to cancel out the downvotes as it is highly frowned upon. Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253383/upvotes-that-cancel-out-downvotes

Comment: @vihan You're not allowed to use `,`.

Comment: @orlp could you run the code on Firefox? That'll allow us to use ES6 features.

Comment: @vihan That's ok.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to *generate* the JS code. We have the [metagolf] tag for that. All languages allowed, no one complains. Answers can even be *readable*! It's actually not too late to change the rules now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## 7,576 chars

## Firefox / Safari 9 (WebKit Nightly)

The main byte-saver is `fill()`

```
alert(Array(48).fill().reduce(falsefalse=>falsefalse.unshift(falsefalse[1]+falsefalse[0]),falsefalse},[1,1]).reverse())
```

Most non-alphanumeric characters (especially `;` and `>`) are very expensive so I'm really trying to minimize their use.

Script

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+[![]]+[][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]())[+(+!![]+[+!![]])]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[]))])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+![]+![]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+!![]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+[]]]+![]+![]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()((![]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]))[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+![]+![]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+!![])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+![]+![]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+[])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+[[]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]([[]])+![]+![]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+[[]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]([[]])+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+!![])+[[]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]([[]])+(+!![])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]])()
```

## Chrome (11,605)

Original:

`;` is very expensive.

```
alert(Array(48).join(0).split(0).reduce(function(falsefalse){return falsefalse.unshift(falsefalse[1]+falsefalse[0]),falsefalse},[1,1]).reverse())
```

Script: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8aFYr0Wp).

Comment: Hey Vihan, I mentioned this on another answer, but `falsefalse` as a variable name is fewer chars than `t` or `f` or anything, might help you shave a few more off! Shame we can't produce more numbers than 50 though because `50` is shorter than `48`...

Comment: @DomHastings would it help to generate two too many and then pop them before printing?

Comment: @JanDvorak Doesn't look like it, tried combinations of `.pop()`, `.shift()` and `.splice()` but they all add too many chars! Think @vihan has it covered! If `alert()`ing at each stage is acceptable it could be possible to skip the reverse entirely though, but I feel that's a bit rule-breaky...

Answer (score 7):

## 15,943 bytes

I just hardcoded the values and used the [JScrewit Compiler](http://jscrew.it/).

Original Code:

```
alert([1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,17711,28657,46368,75025,121393,196418,317811,514229,832040,1346269,2178309,3524578,5702887,9227465,14930352,24157817,39088169,63245986,102334155,165580141,267914296,433494437,701408733,1134903170,1836311903,2971215073,4807526976,7778742049,12586269025])
```

JSFuck Code:

```js
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))[(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[]))))[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]](![])[([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[]))))[+!![]+[+[]]]](([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()((![]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]))[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(+[]+[][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]](([][(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]](![]+[])+[])[+!![]]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[+[]]+([![]][+!(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+!![]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]))[([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]]([]))()
```

Although hardcoding is longer than a golfed generator in normal js, numbers are (comparatively ;P) easily represented in JsFuck.

Answer (score 4):

## <s>30287</s> <s>12419</s> 12288  Bytes

Original golf:

```
for(f=[1,1],t=1;t<49;)f.push(f[t-1]+f[t++]);alert(f)
```

Unshift and Reverse are cheaper than Push for a slight saving:

```
for(f=[1,1],t=48;t;t--)f.unshift(f[0]+f[1]);alert(f.reverse())
```

<s>Doesn't fit! 30K character limit!
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MKCDtnFL) here.</s>

I tried jsfuck.com but that gave me 62399 bytes.

Following the suggestion of Stefnotch, changed compatibility to Chrome only and slashed the count dramatically.
JSFuck generated by [jscrew.it](http://jscrew.it/):

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+!![]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+!![])+([][(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]](![]+[])+[])[+!![]]+(+!![])+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+([][(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]](![]+[])+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](+[![]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](+[![]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+((+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+(+((+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()((![]+[])[+!![]]+(+[![]]))[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+[])+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+!![])+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](+[![]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+!![]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]])()
```

Comment: You can include results that don't fit within SE's character limit by linking to a pastebin or similar.

Comment: You can make your answer a lot shorter by setting the compatibility to Custom and then only selecting Chrome. "Your solution must work on any fresh install of the latest Google Chrome on any OS." That way, you could beat the current best answer.

Answer (score 1):

## <s>12,285</s> <s>12183</s> <s>12069</s> <s>11399</s> <s>11252</s> 11105 Bytes

Original code:

```
f=[1,1];for(i=0;i<48;)f.push(f[i++]+f[i]);alert(f)
```

After removing semicolon and replacing it with '\n': (Thanks [Dom Hasting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings).)

```
f=[1,1]
for(i=0;i<48;)
f.push(f[i++]+f[i])
alert(f)
```

Using 'concat' instead of 'push' to save some bytes:

```
f=[1,1]
for(i=0;i<48;)
f=f.concat(f[i++]+f[i])
alert(f)
```

Updated code:

```
falsefalse =[1,1]
for(false0=0;false0<48;)falsefalse=falsefalse.concat(falsefalse[false0++]+ falsefalse[false0])
alert(falsefalse)
```

Removing empty space:

```
falsefalse=[1,1]
for(false0=0;false0<48;)falsefalse=falsefalse.concat(falsefalse[false0++]+ falsefalse[false0])
alert(falsefalse)
```

Removing empty space after '+':

```
falsefalse=[1,1]
for(false0=0;false0<48;)falsefalse=falsefalse.concat(falsefalse[false0++]+falsefalse[false0])
alert(falsefalse)
```

JSFuck Code:

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](![]+[![]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+!![]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+!![])+([][(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]](![]+[])+[])[+!![]]+(+!![])+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+![]+(+[])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(+[])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](+[![]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+!![]]]+![]+(+[])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]]()[+[]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](+[![]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+![]+![]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+!![]]]+![]+![]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+![]+![]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+![]+(+[])+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+![]+![]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+![]+(+[])+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+![]+![]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]])()
```

Comment: Hey Vasu, you might be able to save bytes using `falsefalse` and `false0` as the variable names instead of `t` and `f` and `\n` is fewer chars than `;` (according to jscrew.it anyway) so you mgiht be able to replace those for a saving too. If it's possible to show the first 52 numbers, 50 is half the size of 48 too... Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem at all, glad to have been able to help! You can remove the extra newline between the `for(i=0;i<48;)` and `f.push` for more of a saving and replacing the variable names will definitely save some `f` = `(![]+[])[+[]]` vs.  `falsefalse` = `![]+[![]]` and `i` = `([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]` vs. `false0` = `![]+[+[]]`. `concat` was the only other way I could see to help reduce that method too!

Comment: Wow that reduced a lot. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

## Firefox, 7446 bytes

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+![]+![]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]()[+!![]+[+!![]]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+[+!![]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]](+!![]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+![]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+![]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]])+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]](![]+[![]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]]+[])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+[]+[![]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+![]+![]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+!![])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[!![]+!![]]+![]+![]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]]]+(+[])+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]])+([(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]((![]+[])[+!![]])+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+![]+![]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+[]+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]))()
```

Source:

```
[].fill.constructor('[...[falsefalse=[1,1]].fill+false+false].reduce('+[].fill.constructor('falsefalse.unshift(falsefalse[1]+falsefalse[0])')+'),alert(falsefalse.reverse())')()
```

Answer (score 0):

## 14,097 Bytes

First time doing one of these or coding in this language so I will come back and see if I can get it smaller

**Original code:**

```
for(i=1;i<51;i++){alert(Math.floor(((Math.pow(1.618033988749, i)/2.2360679775)+.5)))}
```

**JSFuck Code:**

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]+(+(+!![]+[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()(+[]+[+[]]+(+[![]])+![])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()(+[]+[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]())[+(+!![]+[+!![]])])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(+!![]+[+[]]+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))[(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[]))))[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]](![])+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]])())()
```